# How to revert back to a fresh branch on git (removing all uncommitted changes)

Tags: eclipse, git, git-branch, git-reset

How can I revert/delete all my changes that I did manually on local.

Example I have 2 branches

```
1) master branch
2) branch2
```

I checked out branch 2 and started to do some changes locally. I accidentally replaced a word for all the files. So now all my files are unsynced.

I want to start fresh again. (What ever I have in branch 2 that was committed and pushed) and remove all my local changes.

I've tried

```
git pull branch2
git reset --hard
git --hard branch2
git checkout .
```

But my recent changes are still existing in my local. Is there a command to revert this or do I have to clone the branch and start from there?

PS all my local changes were not committed at all.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a `git stash` to temporarily store the changes you made and don't want to commit. And then do a `git stash pop` later to get them back. If you never want to see those changes ever again, then you can overwrite your local changes with a

`git reset --hard`

`git pull`

You said you didn't commit files so there are probably untracked local files that need to be removed. I would run a `git clean -f` . That'll remove the untracked files. If you also need to remove untracked directories (folders) you can do a `git clean -df`

Hope that helps!

Comment: In a case the untracked files are not removed, git add them then git reset.

Answer (score 1):

This will vanish all the changes done on local and pull down the last committed changes on your branch.

```
git reset .
git checkout .
git checkout branch2
git fetch && git reset --hard origin/branch2
```